# Sonarqube for TFS response error 500 on Build

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to analyse a C# code on build in TFS 2015, but it finishes with error 500.

In the server log appears the exception below. It seems that the error comes from MySQL. I changed `max_allowed_packet` variable to 256M but nothing happens:

web.log

```
 2017.03.02 16:03:52 ERROR web[AVqLB+YBzeX47ye1AAR2][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://MyServer:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=PortalMF.QA&projectName=PortalMF-QA
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to insert data of CE task AVqQaDP9V24qvINOIbFD
    at org.sonar.db.ce.CeTaskInputDao.insert(CeTaskInputDao.java:56)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.ReportSubmitter.submitReport(ReportSubmitter.java:103)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.ReportSubmitter.submit(ReportSubmitter.java:71)
    at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:88)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:108)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:74)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:83)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:73)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RoutesFilter.doFilter(RoutesFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (7104646 > 4194304). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3671)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2508)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.sonar.db.ce.CeTaskInputDao.insert(CeTaskInputDao.java:53)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

---

ce.log

```
2017.03.02 16:41:29 ERROR ce[][o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to pop the queue of analysis reports
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
### The error may exist in org.sonar.db.ce.CeQueueMapper
### The error may involve org.sonar.db.ce.CeQueueMapper.selectEligibleForPeek
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:111)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.selectEligibleForPeek(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.db.ce.CeQueueDao.peek(CeQueueDao.java:112)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.InternalCeQueueImpl.peek(InternalCeQueueImpl.java:70)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.tryAndFindTaskToExecute(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:66)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:51)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor57.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor20.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.sonar.db.profiling.NullConnectionInterceptor.getConnection(NullConnectionInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.sonar.db.profiling.ProfiledDataSource.getConnection(ProfiledDataSource.java:323)
    at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.openConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:134)
    at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:61)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:279)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.prepareStatement(ReuseExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:56)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:137)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:96)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:108)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the server logs?

Comment: i've updated the topic with the information, thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was grant access to sonarqube from mysql

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* to username@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```